# How to add items to a form array

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am using reactive forms in an angular 2/4 application and when I try to add a child form group to a form array, I get this error message in the console:

> orderitems.component.html:84 ERROR CONTEXT 
>   DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}

It's pointing to this line in the HTML of the component:

```
<tbody formArrayName="items">
   <tr *ngFor="let item of orderForm.controls.items.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

The error is on the second line on `*ngFor`.

I am constructing the form like this:

```
buildForm(): void {
   this.orderForm = this.fb.group({
   orderNo: '',
   ...
   items : this.fb.array([])
```

And here is the add function

```
addItem(item?: any) {
   const itemsControl = <FormArray>this.orderForm.controls['items'];
   itemsControl.push(item != null ? item : this.initItems());
}
```

Any ideas why this error is being thrown upon adding a new item to the array?

Is there a better way to add items to a nested form array?

Comment: I have an example of adding items to a form array here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/blob/master/APM-Updated/src/app/products/product-edit.component.ts Maybe something there can help?

Comment: what is this possible `item` which is passed to your `addItem` function?